# Thin server running rails freezes on application error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos-sierra, thin

I'm running thin as a rails server for development with `bundle exec rails server thin -p 3000`, but when the application hits an error, rather than logging the error, it freezes, becoming unresponsive to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (but not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>). If I attempt to open a debugger console via `byebug`, `binding.pry`, or `binding.irb`, the same behaviour (freezing and being unresponsive to input) occurs and no debugger prompt is printed. This happens in both ITerm2 and Terminal.

Versions:

Thin: `1.5.1 codename Straight Razor`

Rails: `5.0.6`

Ruby: `ruby 2.4.3p205 (2017-12-14 revision 61247) [x86_64-darwin16]`

ITerm2: `Build 3.1.5`

Terminal: `2.7.3 (388.1.1)`

OS: `macOS Sierra, 10.12.6 (16G1212)`

Comment: Have you tried putting a blanket rescue in your application controller to see if you can rescue the exception to see what it is?  If debuggers don't work have you tried using puts to see where the error is occurring?